# Create a dynamic multiple associative array based on user inputs

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array, query-builder

I am dynamically creating an associative array based on the user inputs because i'm going to use it for my Query builder(bulk insertion). I created an array of dates and I want to use its values as a key value pair to an empty array.

I did try `$array['dates'] = $date->format('D');`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $from = $request->input('from');
    $to = $request->input('to');
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $days= [];
    $startDate = Carbon::parse($from); //parse date to be iterated below
    $endDate = Carbon::parse($to); // same as above

    // return $startDate->format('D');
    for ($date = $startDate; $date->lte($endDate); $date->addDay()) {
        $days['schedule_date'] = $date->format('D');
    }

  dd($days);

}
```

but the result I'm getting is only 1.

```
Array ( [schedule_date] => Wed )
```

I'm expecting 31 results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you always assigning to the same array element:

```
$days['schedule_date'] = $date->format('D');
```

you have an array `$days` with a key `schedule_date`; you are simply replacing this value with each iteration.

Depending how you want the shape of your output you could just push to the array like this:

```
$days[] = $date->format('D');
```

This would yield a simple array (not associative array) like:

```
['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']
```

If you need the `schedule_date` key itself to be an array, do like this:

```
$days['schedule_date'][] = $date->format('D');
```

Comment: Now I see that's the reason why I'm getting the last result of the array which is Wednesday. I will try another approach and I'll post it as soon as I can get an answer. Thank you!